# Is it possible to migrate from subversion to git keeping history of copied branches, tags and trunk?

Tags: git, svn, migration, history

I've seen a number of SO posts about this with no resolution.

I have one subversion repository, hosting multiple projects. I would like to migrate one of those projects to git while preserving a history that contains branch, tag and trunk copies.

This one project originally had the structure:

```
root/
   dir/
      mod1/
         trunk/
         branches/
         tags/
      mod2/
         trunk/
         branches/
         tags/
      ...
```

Initially these projects were developed as independent projects, but turns out that they are more related than we originally thought and we decided to reorganize by copying all the individual trunk, branches and tags directories to be right under `dir/` to look like:

```
root/
   dir/
      trunk/
         mod1/
         mod2/
         ...
      branches/
      tags/
```

My `git svn clone` looks like:

```
git svn clone --no-metadata <svn_url>/root/dir -s git-svn-clone
```

After that finishes and I clean up my branches and tags as per [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git), but when I do a `git log`, I only see history starting at the point at which that branch/tags/trunk was copied in svn.

I've tried `git log --follow` but that doesn't work. I've tried the `-M -C and --find-copies-harder` options and they all show the same thing.

I'd have thought that by making sure that I cloned all the branches, tags and trunks, that git would be able to find the parents from which directories were copied.

Is what I want simply not possible? It wouldn't be the worst thing in the world to not have the history but it would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [subgit](http://subgit.com/) which I have used to migrate my local subversion repository to git.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no turn-key solution to this (at least I don't know any). In situations like this, I alway start with an git svn clone of the root directory, and doing a `git fast-export --no-data` afterwards. Then I write a script, which transforms all those svn branches int git branches, and use this script to generate a fas-import file which in turn creates the git history.

The main problem is that svn merges are easily ignored (depends also if they are correctly recorded in svn), in a way that a merge looks like one big commit in the integratin branch, while the origin branch ends "in the air".

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did that worked flawlessly: (see http://svnrating.com/svn-to-git-migration/)

First, initialize a new repository for the svn to git migration
    $ mkdir migration
    $ cd migration
    $ git svn init  --stdlayout --prefix=svn/

Next, get the svn repository
    $ git svn fetch

If the repository is large, this could take a while. Once you are done, you can push the repository you just created to your remote or use locally.